# Changing notification settings in native email app

Tags: android

Is there a way to change notification settings in the native email app (possibly also gmail)?

I'm thinking about locale plugin which would allow to change notification settings in each app independently. For example disable sound notifications in email app and leave in gmail...

Comment: It's too bad no was the answer. I'm looking for an app that does exactly this. And if I couldn't find one I was going to write one. Changing all of the notification settings individually is a real pain and far too time consuming. An app that manages this would be ideal. Blackberry has provided this functionality for years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to change notification
>   settings in the native email app
>   (possibly also gmail)?

No, sorry. Applications do not have the ability to change other applications' settings, in general.